# Get ID from DataTables-Table

Tags: jquery, datatables

maybe a easy question for all of you, but I'm fairly new to JavaScript/jQuery and how AJAX calls work, so i Need a Little bit of help.

At the Moment im rebuilding my DataTable-Tables to use severside-processing because they grow very big and through this becoming very slow. I allready put a fair amount of time in it to understand how ajaxcall works, etc. but there is one Problem i can't solve: I can't get the ID from the DataTables im working with.

This is my HTML-Part:

```
<table id="tbl_user" class="table table-hover display ajaxTable" width="100%;" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Kostenstelle</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Aktionen</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

This is my javascrip/jQuery-Part:

```
$('.ajaxTable').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'ajaxcall.php',
    data: function(params) {
      var query = {
        ajaxcall: 'getSelectDataTable',
        controlName: $(this).attr("id"),
        length: 14,
        draw: params['draw'],
        start: params['start'],
        search: params['search']['value'],
        columns: params['columns'],
        order: params['order']
      }
      return query;
    }
  },
  columns: [
    {"data": "user_id"},
    {"data": "user_name"},
    {"data": "user_kostenstelle"},
    {"data": "user_status"},
    {"data": "aktionen"}
  ]
});
```

I thought i can easly get the ID with $(this).attr("id") but i was wrong. Any has a Suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to loop through all your tables with the class `.ajaxTable` in order to get their specific `id`:

```
$('.ajaxTable').each(function() { //Loop over your tables
  let that = this;                //Store your current table
  $(that).DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'ajaxcall.php',
      data: function(params) {
        var query = {
          ajaxcall: 'getSelectDataTable',
          controlName: $(that).attr("id"), //Reuse your current table
          length: 14,
          draw: params['draw'],
          start: params['start'],
          search: params['search']['value'],
          columns: params['columns'],
          order: params['order']
        }
        return query;
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        "data": "user_id"
      },
      {
        "data": "user_name"
      },
      {
        "data": "user_kostenstelle"
      },
      {
        "data": "user_status"
      },
      {
        "data": "aktionen"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm!
I thought if i pick a class it will iterate over all tables anyway.
Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel I thought the same as you - in fact, I can see that my table get initialized multiple times if I use a class.  Any additional information as to why the id is not available unless you manually iterate through them?

Answer (score -1):

```html
$('.ajaxTable').DataTable().data().each(function (d){
    console.log(d)
});
```